# Autoware ego vehicle stop in the middle of a route using Open Planner

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am using the Autoware 1.13 Release + Open Planner (common, core_perception, and core_planning) from @Hatem fantastic [fork](https://gitlab.com/hatem-darweesh-autoware.ai). I would like to use Open Planner to achieve decision/path planning and obstacle avoidance with surrounding objects (moving vehicles, static obstacles, etc.)

However, the ego vehicle will sometimes stop in the middle of a route (behavior state is End) after interacting with a moving vehicle on the target lane. The detailed processes I went through and the problems are shown in the [video](https://youtu.be/mR5b6tKYS9Y). It seems like the local paths do not update that "smoothly" and "correctly" as in [Hatem's demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6aCurRXh78&ab_channel=HatemDarweesh).

Besides, another minor thing I founded is that the ego-vehicle will have some offsets of the z-axis (not on the map, but below the map). This can be solved by selecting "use_waypoints_for_z_point_source" in the "wf_simulator". This problem is also demonstrated in my video. I wonder what causes this problem and whether my solution is correct.

Please advise if you have any comments or suggestions, especially for the first problem. Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379458/autoware-ego-vehicle-stop-in-the-middle-of-a-route-using-open-planner/) by [yougeyxt](https://answers.ros.org/users/75368/yougeyxt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2021-06-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yougeyxt](https://answers.ros.org/users/75368/yougeyxt/) on 2021-06-02**:
Hi @Hatem, thanks a lot for your good work of Open Planner, could you please check on this? Please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @yougeyxt ,

I checked your video, nice tutorial for people want to use lane change.

1- height (z) is not a problem with planning, will only affect visualization. and your fix was correct.

2- There was an issue in the replanning for global path. I fixed this issue in openplanner.1.13

kindly check and tell me if everything works fine.

is it okay to save your video to openplanner tutorials playlist ? or if you make a new one after the fix that would be nice.

Regards,

---

Originally posted by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) with karma: 443 on 2021-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yougeyxt](https://answers.ros.org/users/75368/yougeyxt/) on 2021-06-03**:
Hello @Hatem,

Thanks for your reply. To double-check, I am currently using the openplanner.1.13 branch from your fork. Do you mean you just fix something and update the code, and I need to pull the updated openplanner.1.13 from your Gitlab code? But from your [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/hatem-darweesh-autoware.ai/core_planning/-/tree/openplanner.1.13), it seems there is nothing updated? Am I checking the right places?

Sure, I can make a new one after the fix and please save it to openplanner tutorials playlist :).

Best,

**Comment by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) on 2021-06-03**:
Not from gitlab, use [GitHub](https://github.com/hatem-darweesh) instead

**Comment by [yougeyxt](https://answers.ros.org/users/75368/yougeyxt/) on 2021-06-04**:
Hi @Hatem,

After using the GitHub openplanner.1.13, the global path can be correctly replanned. However, there is another thing I noticed:

1. When the ego-vehicle is relocated by using 2D pose estimate in RViz (for example the ego-vehicle has already reached the goal and then I give a new initial position to the ego-vehicle), I thought the local path (and also global path) should be replanned to try to reach the destination. However, it seems the local path did not correctly replanned. I can upload a video if my expression is not clear.

Moreover, currently, I am trying hard to create my vector map (or kml map that can be used for openplanner) correspond to my point cloud map. I have a opendrive format (.xodr) map and I want to convert it to vector map/ kml map. Do you have any suggestions for achieving it? I noticed the ASSURE tool you build, and also TIRE4 tool, and also tools provided in Autoware utilities... But I am not sure which one could best suit the need. Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) on 2021-06-04**:
Hi,

Can you mark this as solved, and create a new post for the other questions.

Thanks.

**Comment by [yougeyxt](https://answers.ros.org/users/75368/yougeyxt/) on 2021-06-04**:
Hi,
Of course, I will create a new post tomorrow.
Thanks.